# EF Error when saving an entity with a collection linked by a foreign key

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

My problem is the following one.

I'm receiving an EF exception with this message:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

For this exception i can figure out by myself that EF is trying to set a null value to an int field that is a non-nullable type.

Here is my context:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class RealEstDBContext : DbContext
    {
        #region Constructors
        public RealEstDBContext() 
            : base("RealEstDBContext")
        {

        }
        #endregion

        #region DBSets
        public DbSet<Caracteristic> Caracteristics { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CaracteristicGroup> CaracteristicGroups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Property> Properties { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PropertyType> ProertyTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Caption> Captions { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
```

Then my models:

```
   public class CaracteristicGroup
    {
        public CaracteristicGroup()
        {
            Caracteristics = new List<Caracteristic>();
        }
        #region Properties
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Caracteristic> Caracteristics {get; set; }
        #endregion
    }

public class Caracteristic
    {
        #region Properties
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Group")]
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
        public virtual CaracteristicGroup Group { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
```

if i try to save a caracteristic group that doesn't contain any caracteristic asociated everithing runs good, but i that group contain one caracteristic EF go throw the exception.

Here is the code for save the group.

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveGroup(CaracteristicGroup caracteristicGroup)
        {
            JsonResult toReturn = new JsonResult();
            toReturn.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;

            try
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    var oldCaracteristicGroup = UnitOfWork.Instance.DataContext.CaracteristicGroups.Include(c => c.Caracteristics).Where(p => p.Id == caracteristicGroup.Id).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (oldCaracteristicGroup == null)
                        UnitOfWork.Instance.DataContext.CaracteristicGroups.Add(caracteristicGroup);
                    else
                    {



                        oldCaracteristicGroup.Name = caracteristicGroup.Name;
                        oldCaracteristicGroup.Description = caracteristicGroup.Description;
                        UnitOfWork.Instance.DataContext.Entry(oldCaracteristicGroup).State = EntityState.Modified;


                        foreach (Caracteristic item in oldCaracteristicGroup.Caracteristics)
                            UnitOfWork.Instance.DataContext.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    }

                    UnitOfWork.Instance.SubmmitWriteChanges();


                    toReturn.Data = new
                    {
                        Success = true,
                        Message = "Caracteristic group Saved",
                        Content = oldCaracteristicGroup != null ? oldCaracteristicGroup.Id : caracteristicGroup.Id
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    string errorMsg = string.Empty;

                    foreach (var state in ModelState)
                        foreach (var error in state.Value.Errors)
                            errorMsg += error.ErrorMessage + Environment.NewLine;

                    toReturn.Data = new
                    {
                        Success = false,
                        Message = errorMsg,
                        Content = ""
                    };
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                toReturn.Data = new
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "An critical erros has ocur in the server. Call your administrator",
                    Content = ""
                };
            }

            return toReturn;
        }
```

Why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to add the [ForeignKey] attribute yourself. Try changing your Caracteristic model to this:

```
public class Caracteristic
{
    #region Properties

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]        
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int CaracteristicGroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual CaracteristicGroup Group { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```